# Как условно отобразить header внутри jsf?

Tags: javascript, iframe, jsf

У меня есть jsf страница, 
Требуется, чтобы в зависимости от переданного в реквесте параметра, например это GET с параметром в url hide, чтобы:
Если hide=true, то скрыть header 
В остальных случаях отображать его.

Как это можно сделать?
Есть вариант с использованием jstl, но он почему-то не работает

```
<c:choose>
        <c:when test="${requestScope['hide']=true}">
        </c:when>
        <c:when test="${param.hide=true}">
        </c:when>
        <c:when test="${paramValues.hide=true}">
        </c:when>
        <c:otherwise>
            <pmp:header/>
        </c:otherwise>
    </c:choose>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<ui:fragment rendered="#{not param['hide']}">
    <div class="some-header">
        ...
    </div>
</ui:fragment>
```